# The select2 plugin don't work in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, jquery-select2, ui-select2

I want t o use Multiple select boxes for tags and head section i put:

```
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

My view:

```
 <div>

{!! Form::label('tags','Select Tags:') !!}
 <select class="form-control select2-multi" multiple="multiple" name="tags">
```

@foreach ($tags as $tag)

```
    <option value='{{ $tag->id }}'>{{ $tag->name }}</option>

 @endforeach

 </select>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(.select2-multi).select2();
```

And in the browser i get this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVoJD.png)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
  $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<br>
<strong>Single Select</strong>
<select class="js-example-basic-single form-control">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<strong>Multi Select</strong>
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" multiple>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

It's working perfectly fine.
make sure you've included all the required `css` and `js plugins`

NOTE:

1. Add this class for single select `js-example-basic-single` option
2. `js-example-basic-multiple` for multi-select option

Comment: I added it : <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script> but its not work :

Comment: jQuery plugin must come first before other plugins. Make sure you double checked it

Comment: I'm not understand whats you mean ?

Comment: You must put jquery.min.js  above select2.min.js or select2.js or any other plugins

Comment: its was .. but still dont work .. 
still show me that : http://i.stack.imgur.com/YVoJD.png